# Get doxygen to display enum values

Tags: enums, constants, doxygen, display

I know Doxygen can display a #define'd symbol along with it's value.

Can doxygen display the constants from an enum definition along with it's value?  I have not found anything in the config docs and bing/google/duckduck is not coming up with anything.

Considering how valuable this would be, there has to be a way.